# Python vncdotool send special characters

Tags: python, vps, vnc

I am using [vncdotool](https://github.com/sibson/vncdotool). When I test the following code below, the **:** turns into **;** and I unable to figure out why it is doing that. Also when I try to send the **~** it will send **`** instead. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import vncdotool
from vncdotool import api

def sendKeys(client, keys):
  for k in keys:
    client.keyPress(k)

hostport = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX::XXXX'
password = 'XXXXXXXXX'

client = api.connect(hostport, password)

command = 'add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8'
sendKeys(client, command)

command = 'cd ~/myfolder/'
sendKeys(client, command)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special characters have been an ongoing problem in vncdotool. The quick and dirty solution is to use `--force-caps`.  The switch sends `<shift>-char` rather than plain `char`.  From the API you can do something similar to

```
client = api.connect()
client.factory.force_caps = True
```

This isn't ideal but without a deeper investigation into why some servers aren't handling special characters as expected it seems to get the job done.

Comment: Alright, so that works! Thank you! Now have another issue... sometimes when I sent commands, it sends in ALL CAPS and of course the commands do not work with CAPS... any idea why?

Comment: My guess is the server is missing the shift-release.  One possible reason is because the servers key buffer is too small.  If so adding ```--delay=1000``` to the command line or putting client.pause(1000) between commands could help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to use shift to send those characters. Hope this helps someone.

```
def sendSpecialKeys(client, keys):
  client.keyDown('shift')
  sendKeys(client, keys)
  client.keyUp('shift')
```